# C# add items to list from class then add list items to listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, class, listbox

I'm a student in a C# class and this is my introductory assignment to Classes, so please bear with me. When the New button is pressed, a CPerson object will be created using the name and phone values and the object will be added to a List<>.

[image]

```
class CPerson 
{ 

    private string m_sName;  
    private string m_sPhone;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.m_sName; }
        set 
        { 

            this.m_sName = value; 
        }
    }
    public string Phone
    {
        get { return this.m_sPhone; }
        set 
        {
            this.m_sPhone = value; 
        }
    }


}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<CPerson> PhoneNum = new List<CPerson>(); //<CPerson> or <string>?
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        newbutton.Enabled = false;
        changebutton.Enabled = false;
        savebutton.Enabled = false;
    }



    private void newbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        changebutton.Enabled = true;
        savebutton.Enabled = true;
        PhoneNum.Add(new CPerson { Name = Namebox.Text + " : ", Phone = phonebox.Text });
        listBox1.Items.Add(PhoneNum); //text = "Collection"

    }
```

The assignment says "The CPerson ToString() override will be used to display the name and phone number in the listbox" as shown in the above image, which I don't necessarily understand, but I'm guessing I have to use something like this?

```
        CPerson data = new CPerson();
        data.ToString();
```

Either way, as the code is now, all I get in my listbox is "(Collection)". Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `listBox1.DataSource = PhoneNum;`  A BindingList<T> would work better.

Comment: thanks! works good so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is asking to override the ToString() method. You can do it like this:

```
class CPerson 
{ 

private string m_sName;  
private string m_sPhone;

public string Name
{
    get { return this.m_sName; }
    set 
    { 

        this.m_sName = value; 
    }
}
public string Phone
{
    get { return this.m_sPhone; }
    set 
    {
        this.m_sPhone = value; 
    }
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return Name + ": " + Phone;
}
```

I did not get right the part of adding to the list, but I assume you can do the following using ToString():

```
listBox1.Items.Add(data.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Close...

```
    class CPerson
    {
        private string m_sName;
        private string m_sPhone;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.m_sName; }
            set
            {

                this.m_sName = value;
            }
        }
        public string Phone
        {
            get { return this.m_sPhone; }
            set
            {
                this.m_sPhone = value;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name + ": " + Phone;
        }
    }
}
```